# dialog or popup in pickList PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, alert, picklist

I want to show pop-up or dialog in pickList , means if user does not select any record ( keeps target empty ) and click submit then one dialog should be shown to user saying that at least one record should be selected. I have used required="true" in pickList for this criteria but not getting how to show pop up in pickList when user clicks submit after unselecting all records.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use primefaces p:growl component to show messages. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml

After form has been submitted you need to check pickList selected value in instance of your org.primefaces.model.DualListModel by calling getTarget() method. 
If it`s empty than create and add FacesMessage:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Message text");
facesContext.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur reply but actually I am already getting the validation message on page by using required attribute of pickList . Instead of this message on page I need error message in popup .